# Using selenium to automate web scraping of google maps search data with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I have tried the following code. I am able to open the browser using selenium and search the results properly however i am unable to scrape the results. Only a handful of the results are being printed. I am unable to figure out the error. Is it due to some wrong commands that i am giving or there is some problem with the scrolling part ?

```
def searchplace():
    Place = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "searchboxinput")
    Place.send_keys("Hotels in my area")
    Submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button")
    Submit.click()

searchplace()

def scroll_to_end():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2) 
def get_hotel_names():
    hotel_names = []
    prev_scroll_height = 0
    while True:
        scroll_to_end()
        new_scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
        if new_scroll_height == prev_scroll_height:
            print("No more hotels to load.")
            break
        prev_scroll_height = new_scroll_height
        time.sleep(2)  
        hotel_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'hfpxzc')  
        for element in hotel_elements:
            aria_label = element.get_attribute("aria-label")
            if aria_label:
                hotel_names.append(aria_label)
    return hotel_names

all_hotel_names = get_hotel_names()

for name in all_hotel_names:
    print(name)

driver.quit()
```